# how to link an html file to another html in flask

Tags: html

my files in templates

```
- main.html
- page1.html
```

my code

```
def main():
    return render_template('main.html')
```

html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<a href="page1.html">users</a>
</body>
</html>
```

it doesn't work and gives me Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the route(url) to the template in the function `main()` using a decorator like this:

```
@app.rout("your/url")
def manin()
   return render_template("your_template.html")
```

Another thing, you should create a folder(directory) called templates, and place all your templates in it so that flask can detect them, otherwise, flask will not detect the templates, unless you tell it to look elsewhere and you do not want to bother yourself with it right now. Just put all your templates in a directory called templates that it in the same level as your app.

Comment: I do that but still gives me the same thing

Answer (score -1):

try this:
In main.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "YourFlaskSafetyKeyHere"

@app.route("/")
def Home():
    return render_template("page1.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

in page1.html:

```
<h1>Home Page</h1>
```

There you go! You just didn't satisfied the requirements of Flask